# Make navbar collapsible with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this navbar and I'm trying to make it collapse so all the links and the button on the right will collapse to a burger menu that, when clicked on, will show a black background with the links listed vertically

```

```
<body>
    <header id="nav-wrapper">
        <img id="logo" src="images/event-logo.png" />
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-list active"><a class="link" href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">SPEAKERS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">AGENDA</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">SPONSORS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">MEDIA</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">disruptHR</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">TRAVEL</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-list"><a class="link" href="">FLOORPLAN</a></li>
                    <li class="link">MORE</li>
                    <button id="tickets-btn">GET TICKETS</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

```

Answer (score 0):

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

just the documentation of bootstrap 4, below the code with your links:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-list nav-item active"><a class="link nav-link" href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">SPEAKERS</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">AGENDA</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">SPONSORS</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">disruptHR</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">TRAVEL</a></li>
        <li class="nav-list nav-item"><a class="link nav-link" href="">FLOORPLAN</a></li>
        <li class="link nav-item"> MORE </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button id="tickets-btn">GET TICKETS</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). Bootstrap 4 is now beta.

https://www.codeply.com/go/4GM7ligFGu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="//placehold.it/130x30"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">AGENDA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SPONSORS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4GM7ligFGu